# Use of unresolved identifier QR Reader

Tags: qr-code, xcode6.3

I have a barcode reader code was working well with Xcode 6.2 but when you upgraded to Xcode 6.3 I got this error message

Use error message of unresolved identifier 'qrCodeFrameView'

this my code

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero

            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
        // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
        // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
        if supportedBarCodes.filter({ $0 == metadataObj.type }).count > 0 {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {


            }
```

Comment: I explained the problem

Comment: Where did you create your "qrcodeframeview" object ?

Comment: Created at the start of viewController, This way var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?